# Form submit issues with Squarespace site using Amazon CDN

Tags: forms, ssl, amazon-web-services, squarespace, content-delivery-network

I have a `Squarespace` site which I put behind the Amazon Cloudfront CDN for added security.  However, the forms on the site don't submit anymore. The submit button simply blinks, and the form does not send. The following console errors are logged:

```
https://www.example.com/api/census/RecordHit 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://www.example.com/api/form/FormSubmissionKey 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://www.example.com/api/census/RecordHit 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Any idea what's going on and a work-around?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 403 forbidden comes because you haven't set the option to allow the request types POST

In CloudFront distribution go to: Behaviours > Allowed HTTP Methods
Select Option: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

Also if you have issues with the site loading, make sure you use .squarespace.com as the origin, rather than ext-cust.squarespace.com. This stumped me for the while too, I think it is to do with the headers that are forwarded.

Comment: We have the same issue, and setting to `.squarespace.com` was not valid in cloudfront. Were you able to get it to save somehow?

Comment: Yes, we stopped using a CDN with squarespace :P